# Grunt cssmin is not generating main.css

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-cssmin, grunt-build-control

When I run `grunt build --verbose` it is telling me that `>> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.`. I also notice that is says `Files: [no src] -> dist/styles/main.css` so if there is no source `[no src]` it makes sense there is nothing being written. At least that is my thinking now. The result is that **main.css** is not being generated.

Why is this happening?

```
Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task
Verifying property cssmin.generated exists in config...OK
Files: bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.css, bower_components/normalize.css/normalize.css -> dist/styles/vendor.css
Files: [no src] -> dist/styles/main.css
Options: report="min"
Reading bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.css...OK
Reading bower_components/normalize.css/normalize.css...OK
Writing dist/styles/vendor.css...OK
File dist/styles/vendor.css created: 194.3 kB → 138.61 kB
>> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.
```

Here is a Gist containing my **Gruntfile.js** :

https://gist.github.com/3lfist/86f1cc3076e01ef5a905

and here is my **index.html** which contains the usemin blocks

https://gist.github.com/3lfist/c39eedeb7c8ef6adae48

Comment: I have the same issue with a yo angular-fullstack build.  To check, I just did a clean setup of an empty project in an empty directory.  I see the same issue with grunt build.  with:  Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task
>> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.
File dist/public/app/app.css created: 161.09 kB → 129.1 kB.   I have been hunting, but no answer yet. - if I see a solution, I will report back.

Comment: I did a 'grunt build:dist --verbose' which gives a few more details: Running "cssmin" task

Running "cssmin:generated" (cssmin) task
Verifying property cssmin.generated exists in config...OK
Files: .tmp/concat/app/vendor.css -> dist/public/app/vendor.css
Files: .tmp/concat/app/app.css -> dist/public/app/app.css
Options: report="min"
Reading .tmp/concat/app/vendor.css...OK
>> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.
Reading .tmp/concat/app/app.css...OK
Writing dist/public/app/app.css...OK
File dist/public/app/app.css created: 161.09 kB → 129.1 kB
--- Still no HELP ---

Comment: If anyone comes across this thread, what was wrong with my app was that I had both grunt-css and usemin, if I did a:

npm uninstall grunt-css 

it worked